# LYX debugging does not allow going to error in document

Tags: errors, lyx, debugging

Lyx produces an error message when compiling, but I cannot find where the error is in the document. When hovering over the errors it says clicking it would take me to the error in the document but it's not working. This makes it very difficult to debug the errors. Please help if you have found a solution to this problem.

[image: Error message]

The complete log view is shown below, but I have similar equations throughout the document and couldn't find which one is erroneous.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. I see an error. Peraphs you have written into your code `\hobx` instead of `\hbox`.

Comment: @Sebastiano No, that is not the actual error. It's just meant as an example.

Comment: Zelalem, you could try clicking "View complete log", and find the first occurrence of "undefined control sequence" in that file. Then you can see the entire error, and it would show you which command is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I not use LyX. I thinked that was as the .log file of the errors. Excuse me. I have misunderstood.

Comment: @TorbjørnT, I tried to look into the complete log it shows part of the equation with the error. The problem is I have plenty of similar equations throughout the document so I can't tell which one is wrong.

Comment: Not sure what the best approach is. You could try Edit -> Find & replace (advanced), in the settings tab select to search only in maths, and search for `\gamma \n`. Edit: it's the `\n` that's the offending macro.

Comment: @TorbjørnT, thanks! the error is \n, it's fixed now. I am curious though, how do one go to specific error in the document by clicking on the error message? I wish this was possible so I can use lyx instead of latex with no worries.

Answer (score 2):

The ams alignments such as `align` read their entire body as a macro argument which means that without using `lyx` any errors that occur within the body of the alignment will be reported at the line number for `\end{align}` This probably makes it hard for a system like lyx to  be more precise.

However the tex log will show you which command is undefined, as it says in the help text that you show this is the last command on the first line of the error log, presumably the "view complete log" button will show this (I don't have lyx to test)